# Jest gql apollo - TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-apollo, ts-jest

Following the guide for `MockedProvider` here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#mockedprovider to run some tests in Jest but I keep getting the following error in the component that I'm trying to test from the test runner:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

  24 | }
  25 | 
> 26 | export const FOO_QUERY = gql(fooQuery);
     |                          ^
  27 |
```

The error seems to suggest that `gql` is `undefined` during the Jest test even though `gql` is working with no issues during development. The error is being flagged from `<FooChildComponent/>`

My test file has:

**edit: added `mocks={mocksArray}` to imply an array of request/results objects**
thanks @Drew Reese

```
    it('does a thing', async () => {
     const App = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocksArray}>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/goFoo']}>
          <FooProvider>
            <FooChildComponent />
          </FooProvider>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </MockedProvider>
    );

    ...

   }
```

node 14
typescript 3.7
ts-jest: 24.2
jest: 24.8
react: 16.12

Comment: Based on the docs alone I don't think an empty array (`mocks={[]}`) in the mock is enough mocking. Looks like you need to also mock a bit of the request and response. This is likely what is missing. "Your mock request's variables object must exactly match the query variables sent from your component."

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond @DrewReese. i missed that detail in my code snippet and you're totally right about and empy `mocks={[]}` prop. i've edited my snippet after your feedback